# WebApp offline not accessible

Tags: web-applications, service-worker, offlineapps, quasar-framework

Currently, I'm developing a WebApp using the `Quasar-Framework` (PWA).

#### The scenario

Testing it inside my web browser, I can see that it is "installed" successfully (using `ServiceWorker`) and it is possible for me to call the URL and use the app with its full functionality. That means, even when the server is down, I can open and use the WebApp as the server was up and running.

#### The Problem

When I try the same (using the app while the server is unreachable) with a Smartphone (`Android 7.1.1` using `Firefox Nightly V 60.0a1` and `Chrome 64.*`), everything works fine *until* I close the tab with the WebApp. When I call the URL again, the app won't open.

#### My question

Is this a *normal* behavior or do I have to consider something special, that someone more experienced can recommend? That would be great.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Not normal behaviour. You have to include your SW code.

Comment: Sorry for the late replay. Did not know, that SW requires secure connection. So the problem was, that I did not provide the app using HTTPS.